# How should I use arrays as a class member in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop

I need to use array as a class property but I am not sure about the correct way. Assume that I have a class called `A` and I need an integer array in it.

- First, if I want a static array with 10 elements, is the following way correct? If not, how should it be?

  ```
  class A {
  public:
      int arr[10];
  };
  ```
- Second, if I want a dynamic array, which one of the followings is correct? If neither of them, I would be appreciated if you explain the reason and correct way.

  ```
  class A {
  public:
     int *arr;
  };
  ```

  ```
  class A {
  public:
     int arr[];
  };
  ```
- Finally, what happens if I initialize a property in class definition as following

  ```
  class A {
  public:
      int arr[] = {1,2,3};
      // or
      int *arr = new int[5];
      // or 
      int number = 5;
  };
  ```

Thanks a lot.

Note: I am aware of that it is much better to use `vector` or that kind of STL data structure but I need to stick to arrays somehow.

Comment: "but I need to stick to arrays" - then use `std::array` rather than C-style arrays and manual memory management.

Comment: *if I want a dynamic array, which one of the followings is correct?* -- Use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: I recommend putting your member variables in `private:`, rather than exposing them in `public:` access.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to do it without STL functionalities. Is `std::array` from STL?

Comment: *I need to use array as a class property* -- A pointer is not an array, but one of your examples uses it.  Also, if you are going to use pointers, get ready to add even more code when or if your object is copied or assigned.  There is much more than just an asterisk `*` and `new[]` to consider if you go down this route.

Comment: *I need to stick to arrays*. Then you are out of luck, C++ does not have dynamic arrays, its has pointers and dynamic allocation, but those techniques do not give you an array.

Comment: @Eljay yeah I know but that is not the scope of my question so it is `public` for simplicity.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Alright, I am a bit confused. So what exactly happens in memory when I used `int *arr = new int[5]` ?

Comment: I got it but what do you mean by **dynamic array** ? For example, are the arrays in Python or JavaScript dynamic?

Comment: Python and JavaScript are different languages altogether.  It makes little sense comparing them to C++.  Bottom line -- C++ has no built-in dynamic array.  Everything you see is simulated, whether you are using `new[]` or whether you're using vector.  The advantage of using `vector` is that the work that you would need to put in to get the "dynamic array" to work properly has already been done for you.

Comment: You need to stick to arrays like you need a hole in the head. Use `std::vector<int>` unless you can think of a reason not to. And the reason had better be a good one.

Answer (score 4):

> First, if I want a static array with 10 elements, is the following way correct?

Yes, that is a correct way.

Some people prefer to wrap the array in a class template such as `std::array`.

> Second, if I want a dynamic array, which one of the followings is correct? If neither of them, I would be appreciated if you explain the reason and correct way.
>
> ```
> class A {
> public:
>    int arr[];
> };
> ```

That is an ill-formed declaration. A member cannot be an array of indeterminate length.

> ```
> class A {
> public:
>    int *arr;
> };
> ```

This is correct as such, but there is no dynamic array created. Using this for owning a dynamic array is bad design because bare pointers should never have ownership.

Even for pointing an array stored elsewhere, this is problematic since the class has no knowledge of the length of the array.

This would be a correct way, assuming the array is owned by the class:

```
class A {
public:
   std::vector<int> arr;
};
```

If the array isn't owned by the class, then following is correct:

```
class A {
public:
   std::span<int> arr;
};
```

`std::span` isn't in the standard until C++20 though, so until then you need to resort to a non-standard implementation.

> Finally, what happens if I initialize a property in class definition as following
>
> ```
> class A {
> public:
>     int arr[] = {1,2,3};
> ```

That is ill-formed because the size of a member cannot be deduced from the initaliser.

> ```
> int *arr = new int[5];
> ```

`new int[5]` is a default member initialiser. It will be used in case no initialiser is provided for the member otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is the `std::array` same with built-in C/C++ `array`?

Comment: `std::array` is a class (template) that contains an array as a member. Using it instead of just an array is mostly different in that it doesn't decay to a pointer which is what an array would do. `std::array` also has a nice deduction feature, which cannot be used in case of a member.

Comment: The other major difference is that std::array's can be assigned to each other using `=`, and regular arrays cannot be assigned to each other.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Furthermore, `std::array` can also be copy-constructed from another, unlike an array.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed-size arrays you can use `int arr[10]` or `std::array<int, 10>`.

For dynamically-sized or resizeable arrays if you cannot use `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` you should use `int*` (`int[]` is not a valid data member type in C++) and implement constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment, move assignment and destructor. See [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for more details.